# Download videos in custom folder and name with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to download videos in a custom folder and name I have overridden some methods of FilePiplines but I didn't achieve my goal .This is my piplines.py code.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
import re

class Test2Pipeline(FilesPipeline):




CONVERTED_ORIGINAL = re.compile('^full/[0-9,a-f]+.mp4$')

# name information coming from the spider, in each item
# add this information to Requests() for individual VIDEOS downloads
# through "meta" dict
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    print ("get_media_requests")
    return [Request(x, meta={'file_name': item["file_name"],'file_save':item['file_save']})
            for x in item.get(self.files_urls_field, [])]

def file_path(self, request, response, info):
    print("file_path")

    for key, file, buf, in super(Test2Pipeline, self).file_path(response, request, info):
        if self.CONVERTED_ORIGINAL.match(key):
            key = self.change_filename(key, response)
        yield key, file, buf


def change_filename(self, key, response):
    return "{}/{}.mp4".format(response.meta['file_name'][0], response.meta['file_save'][0])
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code in your question? Could you also explain what your code is currently doing, and what you would want it to do instead?

Comment: I want  to download videos I change my code according to what scrapy explains in its documentation but I can't download anything

Comment: The code in your question does not seem properly indented. Does it look the same in your local file? Could you fix the indentation in your question?